# Bijection between a point in variety and the set of k-algebra homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

[Bijection between a variety $X$ and $\hom(k[X], k)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305725/bijection-between-a-variety-x-and-homkx-k)

I found the above question is very interesting. Despite the illuminating answer provided in the link. How could we use Nullstellensatz to prove surjectivity?

I believe that $k[X]$ should be the coordinate algebra for some variety $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\psi$ be a $k$-linear homomorphism. Let $\psi(x_i) = p_i$ and $p = (p_1,...,p_n) \in \Bbb A^n$. Then $\psi$ agrees with $ev_p$ on each of the $x_i$. Linearity gives that the homomorphisms agree on scalars too, so they agree on any polynomial.

Thus $\psi = ev_p$.

Finally, let $f$ be in the ideal defining $X$. $\psi(f) = \psi(0) = 0$. Thus $p \in X$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I am trying to elaborate your comment. Please correct me if I do not make any sense. I think the $x_i$'s are the generators of the coordinate ring $k[X]\cong k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]/I(X)$? (since the coordinate ring is finitely generated so that we can pick a set of generators.)  Then since $f$ is in the ideal, say A, defining $X$, we have $f\in A\subseteq I(X)$. so $\psi(f)=0$? But how this proves surjectivity?  Thanks!

Comment: You are absolutely right. This proves surjectivity onto the hom-set by showing that every $k$-linear homomorphism in the hom-set is actually an evaluation homomorphism corresponding to a single point in $X$.

Comment: Many thanks! So the idea is that we first pick a point in the affine n-space. Then we found that $\psi$ will agree with $ev_p$. Last we prove that in fact, this $p$ is in the variety $X$. Therefore for each $k$-linear homomorphism, we found a $p\in X$ such that $\psi=ev_p$. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: That‘s almost it: you first fix $\psi$ and define a point $p$ by the values that $\psi$ gives when evaluated at the $x_i$. Then $\psi$ is equal to the evaluation at that point $p$.

Comment: many many thanks! Also, it appears that the injectivity is not quite obvious to me....could you please give me some suggestions about the injectivity.

Comment: I mean, if I took $ev_a=ev_b$, what makes it true that $a$ must be $b$?

Comment: Let $ev_a = ev_b$. A necessary condition for $ev_a$ to be an evaluation homomorphism is that $ev_a(X) = a$, i.e. $ev_a(x_i) = a_i$. By assumption, $ev_a(X) = ev_b(X) = a$, so $a = b$.